# How to debug "MethodNotAllowedHttpException" in Symfony?

Tags: php, mysql

I created a backend for my site with an "add product" function but when I add it I do not create the product on the table and I have this error

I have this error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message
```

My form:

```js
@extends('admin.layout.admin')

@section('content')

 <h3>Aggiungi Prodotto</h3>

 <div class='row'>
   <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

    {!! Form::open(['route'=>'product.create','method'=>'post', 'files'=>true]) !!}

   <div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('nome', 'Nome') }}
    {{ Form::text('nome', null, array('class'=> 'form-control')) }}
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('descrizione', 'Descrizione') }}
    {{ Form::text('descrizione', null, array('class'=> 'form-control')) }}
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('prezzo', 'Prezzo') }}
    {{ Form::text('prezzo', null, array('class'=> 'form-control')) }}
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('category_id', 'Categoria') }}
    {{ Form::select('category_id',[1=>'Flauti'],null,['class'=> 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Seleziona Categoria']) }}

   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('image', 'Image') }}
    {{ Form::file('image',array('class'=> 'form-control')) }}
   
   </div>

  {{ Form::submit('create', array('class'=>'btn btn-->default')) }}

  {!! Form::close() !!}

   </div> 

 </div>


  
@endsection
```

My routes:

```css
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'frontcontroller@index');
Route::get('/index.html', 'frontcontroller@index');
Route::get('/checkout.html', 'frontcontroller@checkout');
Route::get('/furniture.html', 'frontcontroller@furniture');
Route::get('/login.html', 'frontcontroller@login');
Route::get('/products.html', 'frontcontroller@products');
Route::get('/register.html', 'frontcontroller@register');
Route::get('/single.html', 'frontcontroller@single');
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('home');;

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin' ,'middleware'=>'auth'], function () {
  Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('admin.index');
  })->name('admin.index');

Route::resource('product','ProductsController');
Route::resource('category','CategoriesController');

});
```

My controller:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Category;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $categories=Category::pluck('nome','id');
        return view('admin.product.create',compact('categories'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $formInput=$request->except('image');
        //image upload
        $image=$request->image;
        if ($image){
            $imageName=$image->getClientOriginName();
            $image->move('image',$imageName);
            $formInput['image']=$imageName;
    }
        Product::create($formInput);
        return redirect()->route('admin.index');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your questions.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Please change following line in your form

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'product.create','method'=>'post', 'files'=>true]) !!}
```

to

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'product.store','method'=>'post', 'files'=>true]) !!}
```

basically, create routes are to show forms when you use Resources. But when you want to submit the form you need to submit to .store or if it's an edit form then submit to .update route.

Comment: But now i have this problem:                                                                  
                                                                                                               "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Product' not found"

Comment: @Piermauro: if fixing an error gets you a new error, then you have some debugging to do. It is much easier (and quicker) for you to do it, than for someone to respond to a string of errors. Can you make a try first? Hardik may be able to help, but do some research first - you may be able to do it yourself.